# Extraction of a decision boundary (LDA) after a systematic querying of the feature space and convolution with Sobel filter (examples in numpy)

Tags: machine-learning, classification, categorical-data, convolution, numpy

I am doing some experiments with [LDA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_discriminant_analysis) (*Linear Discriminant Analysis*), in python.

Now I am at the point in which I would like to display the separation planes in the 3-dimensional feature space.

I tough that a solution could be, initially, querying the feature space so that for each coordinate ("voxel"), the inferred category can be attached. This category is the *argmax* of the posterior probabilities inferred for each category.

Till here everything went fine, and the operation, although computationally expensive, was successful.

At this point I would like a reliable method to extract a decision boundary from the queried feature space. In other words, I would like to get a 3D matrix filled with zeroes except for the occurrences of the separation plane, which should be ones.

In order to use existing methods and not to re-invent the wheel, I decided to use the well-known [Sobel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobel_operator) filter in order to give some values at the points that belong to the decision boundary and zeroes elsewhere.

I will illustrate what I am doing with a simple example, using *numpy*.
Let's assume that the following forged matrix represents a 2D feature space that has been queried with a classifier:

```
>>> m = np.fliplr(np.triu(np.ones([10,10]))) + np.triu(np.ones([10,10]))
>>> m
array([[ 2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.],
       [ 1.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  2.,  2.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.]])
```

As you can see, the matrix `m` could well represent a bi-dimensional space partitioned in several categories by a classifier.

Now, if I convolve that matrix with the Sobel filter, I obtain something that is promising:

```
>>> from scipy.ndimage.filters import sobel
>>> sobel(m)
array([[ 1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0., -1., -1.],
       [ 2.,  3.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0., -1., -3., -2.],
       [ 1.,  3.,  3.,  1.,  0.,  0., -1., -3., -3., -1.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  3.,  3.,  1., -1., -3., -3., -1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  3.,  2., -2., -3., -1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0., -1., -3., -2.,  2.,  3.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0., -1., -3., -3., -1.,  1.,  3.,  3.,  1.,  0.],
       [-1., -3., -3., -1.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  3.,  3.,  1.],
       [-3., -4., -1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  4.,  3.]])
```

Since I want to use only zeroes and ones in the representation of the decision boundary, I can do the following:

```
>>> (np.abs(sobel(m)) > 0).astype(int)
array([[1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]])
```

As you can see, now I have something that resembles what I would like to obtain, but still not: the decision boundary is too thick, almost three times that what is necessary.

I could attempt to solve the problem by setting a different threshold value:

```
>>> (np.abs(sobel(m)) > 2).astype(int)
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]])
```

The problem is that this threshold value ($2$) is dependent on the context. What if the categories are in larger number, or differently numbered, or if I have an arbitrary number of dimensions? This is clearly not working.

Do you have any ideas on how to solve this problem? Maybe another filter for the convolution or a different algorithm?

thank you! :)

Comment: Just for your info: there is a number of related questions you might want to check. Search `lda decision boundary`.

Comment: This looks more like a question on programming, not on statistics. You might get better advices on StackOverflow.